# patsubst's returned value when no pattern found

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to send "sub-make" commands to a subdirectory. I have a Parent Directory with a "top_level" Makefile and a child directory with its own Makefile.

My parent Makefile has a target line as follow :

```
target%:
    make -C sub_dir $(patsubst target-%,%,$@)
```

I can do in the parent folder:

> make target-clean && make target-all

It will be interpreted as :

> make -C sub_dir clean && make -C sub_dir all

I want to be able to do:

> make target

but in this case, I get :

> make -C sub_dir target.o

I was expecting that while "patsubst" does not find the pattern, it will return either nothing or the tested expression. But it returns this "target.o".

***Can someone explain it to me ? How can I manage to get nothing ?***

I tried these expressions without success:

```
make -C sub_dir $(patsubst target%,%,$@)
make -C sub_dir $(patsubst -%,%,$(patsubst target%,%,$@))
make -C sub_dir $($(patsubst -%,%,$(patsubst target%,%,$@)):.o=)
```

The last one is tricky, it gives:

> make -C sub_dir
>   make[1]: Entering directory /home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/parent/sub_dir'
>   make[1]: 'subtarget' is up to date.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/parent/sub_dir'
>   cc   target.o   -o  target
>   cc: target.o: No such file or directory
>   cc: no input files
>   make: *** [target] Error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a pattern must match one or more characters.  So, this pattern:

```
target%:
```

does not match the target name `target`, because there are no characters left over to match the pattern.

So, `make` looks for another implicit rule that can be used to build `target` and it finds the built-in rule:

```
% : %.o
```

so it tries to build `target.o`.  *This* target *will* match the pattern `target%` with a stem of `.o`, so it tries to use your rule to build that.

To specifically answer your question, any word that does not match the substitution pattern in `patsubst` will be passed through without changing it.

Answer (score 1):

The `target%` pattern matches but only with at least one character for the `%`, not zero. From the GNU make manual:

> A pattern rule contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them) in the
>   target; otherwise, it looks exactly like an ordinary rule. The target
>   is a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’ matches any nonempty
>   substring, while other characters match only themselves.

So `target` does not match and make uses its implicit rules to build `target`: build `target.o` and then `target` from `target.o`. When trying to find a way to build `target.o`, the pattern rule matches and the recipe:

```
make -C sub_dir $(patsubst target-%,%,$@)
```

is expanded. But as `target.o` does not match `target-%`, `patsubst` does nothing and your recipe becomes:

```
make -C sub_dir target.o
```